# SharedPreferences data becomes default when entering loop

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a SharedPreferences code that actually works but when I try to initialize the datas with my Views, it suddenly becomes default values, to be specific only the boolean arrays spLayoutV[] and spBakiV[]. Others work like a charm.

```
    retrieveData();
    int n;
    for(n = 0; n < 17 ; n ++){
        i = n + 1;
        TextView tvWarna = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("warna" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        TextView tvWarnaBaki = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("warnaBaki" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        TextView tvMenstruasi = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("menstruasi" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        TextView tvMenstruasiBaki = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("menstruasiBaki" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        TextView tvStatus = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("status" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        TextView tvStatusBaki = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("statusBaki" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        TextView tvTempoh = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("tempoh" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        TextView tvTempohBaki = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("tempohBaki" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        LinearLayout layoutHari = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("layoutHari" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        LinearLayout layoutBaki = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("layoutBaki" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));

        if(MainActivity.this.spLayoutV[n]){
            layoutHari.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            layoutHari.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if(MainActivity.this.spBakiV[n]){
            layoutBaki.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            layoutBaki.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        Log.v("hari initialize", "" + spLayoutV[n]);
        Log.v("baki initialize", "" + spBakiV[n]);

        tvWarna.setText(spWarnaDarah[n]);
        tvWarnaBaki.setText(spWarnaDarahBaki[n]);
        tvMenstruasi.setText(spMenstruasi[n]);
        tvMenstruasiBaki.setText(spMenstruasiBaki[n]);
        tvTempoh.setText(spTempoh[n]);
        tvTempohBaki.setText(spTempohBaki[n]);
        tvStatus.setText(spStatus[n]);
        tvStatusBaki.setText(spStatusBaki[n]);
    }



//toSaveData
public void saveData(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs files", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    int n;
    for(n = 0; n < 17; n++) {
        i = n + 1;
        TextView tvWarna = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("warna" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        TextView tvWarnaBaki = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("warnaBaki" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        TextView tvMenstruasi = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("menstruasi" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        TextView tvMenstruasiBaki = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("menstruasiBaki" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        TextView tvStatus = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("status" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        TextView tvStatusBaki = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("statusBaki" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        TextView tvTempoh = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("tempoh" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        TextView tvTempohBaki = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("tempohBaki" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        LinearLayout layoutHari = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("layoutHari" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        LinearLayout layoutBaki = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("layoutBaki" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));

        editor.putString("menstruasi" + n, tvMenstruasi.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("menstruasiBaki" + n, tvMenstruasiBaki.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("tempoh" + n, tvTempoh.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("tempohBaki" + n, tvTempohBaki.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("warna" + n, tvWarna.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("warnaBaki" + n, tvWarnaBaki.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("status"+ n, tvStatus.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("statusBaki" + n, tvStatusBaki.getText().toString());


        Toast.makeText(this, "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
        LinearLayout layoutHari = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("layoutHari" + (i + 1), "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        LinearLayout layoutBaki = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("layoutBaki" + (i + 1), "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
        boolean hariV = false;
        if (layoutHari.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            hariV = true;
        } else {
            hariV = false;
        }

        boolean bakiV = false;
        if (layoutBaki.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            bakiV = true;
        } else {
            bakiV = false;
        }

        editor.putBoolean("hariV" + i, hariV);
        editor.putBoolean("bakiV" + i, bakiV);
    }

    editor.apply();
}
```

At retrieveData() I actually checked the log and see how the data is nicely done and no problem, but then when entering the for-loop suddenly the boolean array all becomes default false values. I can't see why, please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please consider the editor does its job asynchronously when calling .apply(). For your quick test case, you should probably use .commit() to see if the problem lies there.

Comment: I changed it, but still the same.

Comment: this is the end of my onCreate btw, so I can't see any other place

Comment: You log with `Log.v("hari initialize", "" + spLayoutV[n]);`, but you test with `if(MainActivity.this.spLayoutV[n]){` - are these the same "spLayoutV"s?  (is this code from your MainActivity class?)   Also, can you add a `Log.v("hari initialize", "" + MainActivity.this.spLayoutV[n]);` immediately before the `for` loop (ie where you have the `int n;`)

Comment: Yes, both are the same. I just did that in case it tweaked the problem but still the problem is there.

Comment: yeah the Log.v before the loop is already made in the retrieveData() method. So there the datas are like expected, some true and false, but in the loop it doesn't do the same.

Comment: Okay, turns out I just have to insert that loop into the retrieveData() method. Don't know why it wouldn't just work the way I did, but at least I won't be spending 2 hours on the same problem. Still, thanks for the answers, would like to know why though.